# cocos2d-x 3.9 Android marshmallow c++ to Java JNI

Tags: java-native-interface, cocos2d-x

**Error:**

[image: error]

**Java function:**

[image: java]

I am making game using cocos2d-x 3.9. I could unity ads in my game using my code. But in Android 6.0.1 my code is not working. Everytime when I execute jni function, my app will down. How can I solve this problem?

I heard, in Android 6.0.1 have strict jni policy.

I am searching now..., but I have no much time... if you know about that, help me...

Comment: It would be better to paste errors and code as a text instead of an image.

Comment: Maybe paste the actual C++ JNI code so we can see what you did wrong :)